# What do i need to create a CLI game? Any useful resources?

Tags: command-line, ncurses

So have spent some time, and have decided to make a small game as a sideproject while I'm in school.

I'd like to make a command line game, perhaps some kind of rpg or mud.
My question is, what do I need to make this a reality?

I've looked at ncurses, and have been reading some documentation, is this a necessary step, or is there something easier? Are there any other particular technologies I will need compared to a regular command line application I might make it school?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need two things:

1. A game engine
2. An interface

This is the exact same thing you need for a GUI game. The only only ONLY differences are your input and output mechanism.

So, write your game engine, make sure it's adaptable, and then your command line interface to control that engine.

========= Edit in regards to comments: =========

The goal of any interface is to map user requests to engine requests. Without knowing what language you're in, the specifics are going to be a bit... well ... nonspecific.

I can tell you how I would do it in Java.

I would create a UserRequest class with the following basic characteristics:

abstract class UserRequest {

```
protected GameEngine engine;
protected String command;
protected int numArgs;

public UserRequest(GameEngine engine) { 
    this.engine = engine; 
    this.command= command; 
    this.numArgs= numArgs; 
}

public abstract void callback(User user, String[] args);

protected void checkArgs(String[] args) {
    if(args == null || args.length != numArgs) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("your args suck...");
    }
    if(!args[0].equals(command)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("commands don't match");
}
```

}

In my interface, I would have a `Map<String,UserRequest>` that is populated like this:

```
Map<String,UserRequest> behaviors = new HashMap<String,UserRequest>();
behaviors.add("MOVE",new UserRequest(engine,"MOVE",2) {
    // define the engine callback
    public void callback(User user, String[] args) {
        // assume args[0] is command
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        engine.move(user,x,y);
    }
}

public void repl() {
    while(true) {
        // assume you have a form of input - scanner perhaps?
        String inputline = acquireNextInputLine();
        String[] tokens = inputline.split("\\s"); // default split on white space
        UserRequest behavior = behavior.get(tokens[0]);
        if(tokens == null) displayError(inputLine);
        try { behavior.callback(currentUser,tokens); }
        catch(Exception e) displayError(e); // assume you have better error reporting than this!
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not extremely difficult to test an engine without an interface? And interface is very broad. What tech could be used for the interface?

Comment: @Black it's impossible to test without an interface, actually. And yes, interface is very broad. You can use command line, you can use GUI, you can use programmatic calls (which are required for automated testing.) Think of your game engine like a giant box with buttons. The interface is just something that can push the buttons. You can push based on command line, or gui, or a program. You could push based on random numbers, it doesn't matter.

Comment: If you take nothing else away from this, **Make your engine, then your interface**. You don't need to make the entire engine all at once. Implement a couple features (logging in, moving) then make your interface to test them. Then add another feature to the engine. Then adapt your interface. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Perhaps i need to redefine the question. I don't have problems making the engine, as that is fairly standard programming for what I want to do (remember the keyword small). Its specifically the interface by your definition. Particularly, a command-line interface, and ways to make one.

Comment: @Black added how I might do this in Java - particularly I'd use anonymous classes to provide callbacks to the engine.

Comment: Alright. but that doesn't really answer the question. You used the example of moving a user. How can I move a symbol on the terminal without moving the line (baked interface). As far as I know, ncurses is an example of how to do it. is there any easier way?